# How can I fix Invalid Publisher ID to valid publisher for my facebook page?

Tags: facebook

When I go to my app dashboard, Alert show

Your app is receiving errors from Follow Plugin

In the last three hours 90% of the calls to the method Follow Plugin resulted in errors.

Error Code

3703

Error Description

Invalid Publisher ID

Error Count

47781

This may be result of a recent change you made to Contact iMyanmarAds, or a failure to comply with a recent breaking change.

How do I fix my invalid publisher ID to valid publisher ID

[Invalid Publisher ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOw9t.jpg)

Comment: That sounds like you are simply using the Follow plugin with an invalid profile address.

Comment: So how can I go and add valid profile address

Comment: Well you should know where you embedded the plugin.